# R - kableExtra - footnote() : Difficulty to code the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, kableextra

The aim of this operation is to add a symbol into the first column of "voy_tranches" table if the ratio object corresponding to the time slot and calculated into the "JO_ratio_tranches" table is less than 5% (appearing in red in the table).

[image: voy_tranches table]

```
> dput(voy_tranches)
structure(list(tranches = c(".1_JO[4h_7h[", ".2_JO[7h_9h[", ".3_JO[9h_12h[", 
".4_JO[12h_15h30[", ".5_JO[15h30_18h[", ".6_JO[18h_20h[", ".7_JO[20h_22h[", 
".8_JO[22h_4h["), voy = c(2207, 13051, 14049, 19055, 20094, 7618, 
2544, 704), montees = c(847, 6912, 7701, 11008, 10820, 4082, 1286, 352), dist = c(2.61, 1.89, 1.82, 1.73, 1.86, 1.87, 1.98, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000121ef0>)
```

[image: JO_ratio_tranches table]

```
> dput(JO_ratio_tranches)
structure(list(chem = c("257-ROG1D-NOR4-THOM-LIED3-DVA3", "302-DVA3-DVI4-BOR7-PAIX-ROG1A"), dir = c("R", "A"), `.1_JO[4h_7h[_txcouv` = c(6.7, 6.5), `.2_JO[7h_9h[_txcouv` = c(3.9, 7), `.3_JO[9h_12h[_txcouv` = c(4.5, 5.7), `.4_JO[12h_15h30[_txcouv` = c(5.8, 7), `.5_JO[15h30_18h[_txcouv` = c(3.7, 6.3), `.6_JO[18h_20h[_txcouv` = c(4.1, 5.3), `.7_JO[20h_22h[_txcouv` = c(3.3, 3.9), `.8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv` = c(2.9, 3.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000121ef0>, sorted = "chem")
```

I'm trying to vectorize this code into a for loop but I always have an error message and I don't know how to solve it !

```
ratio_1 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.1_JO[4h_7h[_txcouv` < 5, `.1_JO[4h_7h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_1)){voy_tranches[1,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[1,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_2 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.2_JO[7h_9h[_txcouv` < 5, `.2_JO[7h_9h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_2)){voy_tranches[2,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[2,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_3 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.3_JO[9h_12h[_txcouv` < 5, `.3_JO[9h_12h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_3)){voy_tranches[3,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[3,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_4 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.4_JO[12h_15h30[_txcouv` < 5, `.4_JO[12h_15h30[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_4)){voy_tranches[4,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[4,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_5 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.5_JO[15h30_18h[_txcouv` < 5, `.5_JO[15h30_18h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_5)){voy_tranches[5,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[5,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_6 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.6_JO[18h_20h[_txcouv` < 5, `.6_JO[18h_20h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_6)){voy_tranches[6,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[6,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_7 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.7_JO[20h_22h[_txcouv` < 5, `.7_JO[20h_22h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_7)){voy_tranches[7,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[7,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

ratio_8 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv` < 5, `.8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_8)){voy_tranches[8,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[8,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}
```

OK !

```
for(i in JO_ratio_tranches[, grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches))]){
ratio[[i]] <- JO_ratio_tranches[JO_ratio_tranches[[i]] < 5, ]
if(!is_empty(ratio[[i]])){voy_tranches[i, 1] <- paste(voy_tranches[i, 1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}
}
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet ‘ratio’ introuvable Calls : 
>   … handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

R doesn't find the "ratio" object ! :( Could you, please, help me to correct this for loop ?

**EDIT : @user2554330 find the solution by adding ratio <- list() before the loop but an other problem appears : the for loop only print the results of the last loop ! :(**

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: And what is the error? Please post its message verbatim in body of post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `ratio` list before you start adding elements to it.  Simply add the line

```
ratio <- list()
```

before your loop, and things should be fine.  (Of course, I can't test this advice, because you didn't post a reproducible example...)

Edited to add:
Now the example is reproducible (after fiddling with the dput values a little to make them usable).  The problem is in your for loop:

```
 for(i in JO_ratio_tranches[, grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches))])
```

The standard form for a for loop is

```
 for(i in v)
```

where `v` is a vector, but you give

```
 JO_ratio_tranches[, grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches))]
```

which is not a vector.  I'm not sure what your intention is here; maybe you want

```
 for(i in grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches)))
```

instead?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! It works ! Unfortunately, an other problem appears ! :( My for loop only shows the result of the last loop: ratio_8 <- JO_ratio_tranches[`.8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv` < 5, `.8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv`]
if(!is_empty(ratio_8)){voy_tranches[8,1] <- paste(voy_tranches[8,1], footnote_marker_symbol(1))}

Comment: How can I have the results from every loop and not the last one, please? Thanks again for your help !

Comment: You should edit the question to do two things:  most importantly, include some data so it is a reproducible example.  Then add the second part of your question.

Comment: Please use `dput` instead to produce code we can run to make your datasets (or similar ones).  It's too hard to enter data from a screen shot.

Comment: Hi user2554330 ! Thanks a lot for your answer ! I haven't been notified of your updated message ! Sorry for the late reply ! I've rectified my code but I was wondering if I shouldn't also do a nested for loop in this case ?